# Compute leaderboard of competitive riders throughout a season

Tags: python, mysql, complexity, pandas

I have a table in my DB that contains Riders as rows and their points throughout the season as columns. Here are the columns:

```
['name', 'wwq_id', 'wwq_code', 'year', 'round1_qualy', 'round1_final', 
'round1_timed', 'round1_total_qualy', 'round1_total_qualy_position', 
'round1_total_final', 'round1_total_final_position', 'round1_total_timed', 
'round1_total_timed_position', 'round1_total', 'round1_total_position'...etc
```

The `'round1_qualy', 'round1_final', 'round1_timed'` all come from different tables and are added using another function. Once they are in the DB all of `total` columns are calculated using generated columns in MySQL.

I need to calculate the position of the rider at different points in the season. I.E. After round one qualy, after round two final, etc.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
def set_positions():
    """Add positions to the DB for each column in our overall table"""
    engine = sql.create_engine(MYSQL_CON_STRING)
    connection = engine.connect()
    trans = connection.begin()

    # Men, Women, Junior
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        table = category + '_overall'
        df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM {0}'.format(table), engine)
        points_columns_list = [col for col in df.columns
                               if 'total' in col and 'position' not in col]

        # Calculate the rank based on current total points column and
        # insert into current column index + 1
        for points_column in points_columns_list:
            position_index = df.columns.get_loc(points_column) + 1
            position_column = df.columns[position_index]
            current_points = df.groupby('year')
            position = \
                current_points[points_column].rank(ascending=0,
                                                   method='min').astype(int)
            df.loc[:, position_column] = position.values

            # No points awarded in this and/or previous rounds. Everyone is 
            # at 0 so everyone is rank 1
            df.loc[(df[points_column] == 0)
                   & (df[position_column] == 1), position_column] = 'NULL'

            # Add rows to the DB
            for row in df.itertuples():
                connection.execute('UPDATE {0} '
                                   'SET {1} = {2} '
                                   'WHERE year = {3} and name = "{4}"'
                                   ''.format(table, position_column,
                                             getattr(row, position_column),
                                             getattr(row, 'year'),
                                             getattr(row, 'name')))
        trans.commit()
    connection.close()
```

The code works perfectly, it just takes a long time. This function doesn't get executed very often, but considering there are about 8000 rows per table, it takes a bit of time.

Is there any way to get the complexity down?

Comment: Accidentally posted outside of my account(as a guest) so I can't comment. Thanks for your input! The only problem is that there are generated columns and pre-defined datatypes in the table so I'm not able to recreate it without breaking the data pipeline. Thinking about it now, that could have been a bad idea to use them...

Answer (score 3):

You should strive to reduce the number of queries to your DB. Instead of updating the whole table, row by row, each time you compute a new value, you could:

1. load the data (using [`pd.read_sql_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html));
2. perform the computation of the positions (this may require you to use `None` or `pd.np.NaN` instead of `'NULL'`);
3. write the whole new table at once at the end (using [`df.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)).

The rewrite could look like:

```
def set_positions():
    """Add positions to the DB for each column in our overall table"""
    engine = sql.create_engine(MYSQL_CON_STRING)
    connection = engine.connect()
    trans = connection.begin()

    # Men, Women, Junior
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        table = category + '_overall'
        df = pd.read_sql_table(table, engine)
        compute_positions_for_table(df)
        df.to_sql(table, engine, if_exists='replace')
        trans.commit()
    connection.close()


def compute_positions_for_table(df):
    points_columns_list = [col for col in df.columns
                           if 'total' in col and 'position' not in col]

    # Calculate the rank based on current total points column and
    # insert into current column index + 1
    for points_column in points_columns_list:
        position_index = df.columns.get_loc(points_column) + 1
        position_column = df.columns[position_index]
        current_points = df.groupby('year')
        position = current_points[points_column].rank(ascending=0, method='min').astype(int)
        df.loc[:, position_column] = position.values

        # No points awarded in this and/or previous rounds. Everyone is 
        # at 0 so everyone is rank 1
        df.loc[(df[points_column] == 0)
               & (df[position_column] == 1), position_column] = None
```

And even if you can't "replace" the table, you should still update the table only once at the end of the computation rather than at each new column computation.